# Cannot use 'kaggle.competitions' in Kaggle kernel

Tags: python, kaggle

I am trying to use a Python module in the remote Kaggle kernel, but when I run, `from kaggle.competitions import nflrush`, this error appears:

```
Could not find kaggle.json. Make sure it's located in /root/.kaggle. Or use the environment method.
```

- I am using Kaggle Notebooks.
- The Nlf Rush was a competition in kaggle that ended 2 months ago
- `os.getcwd()`, gives me: `'/kaggle/working'`
- `os.listdir()`, gives me: `['.ipynb_checkpoints', '__notebook_source__.ipynb']`

But I don't know how to add the credentials kaggle.json in the Kaggle remote kernel.
Or is it because the competition is over?

Comment: and what code do you use? Where is file - on server or on local computer ? Did you try to use full path to file ? What do you get with `os.getcwd()` and `os.listdir()` ?

Comment: @furas I am using the notebooks in kaggle website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ones managing the competition made an R Version of the module. The problem with Python still persists.
Here is the link for the R version: https://www.kaggle.com/wcukierski/official-r-starter-notebook-nfl-big-data-bowl

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because your notebook is not attached to the dataset.

See this forum post for details on how to do so: https://www.kaggle.com/c/nfl-big-data-bowl-2020/discussion/113684.

> the easiest is to create it from within the competition: click the "Notebooks" tab on any page in the competition — or just go here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/nfl-big-data-bowl-2020/notebooks — and click on "New Notebook" then the notebook should be set up properly.

Comment: I created a new notebook and it still gives me the same error.